# How does ultrasound imaging localize points in the $x$-$y$ plane?

Tags: acoustics, applied-physics, medical-physics, instrument

Lots of sources describe how ultrasound imaging uses the time differences between wave emission and reception to calculate distances to points in the body. This makes sense for how localization works in the $z$-direction. But how does it localize points in the $x$-$y$ plane, forming a detailed 2D image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ultrasound transducer transmits a very short focused pulse (less than a mm in width--and also in length) say at a 45 degree angle to the transducer face and then records the echoes as a function of time. Each recorded echo becomes an image pixel. It then repeats this at say a 44.5 degree angle, next a 44 degree angle, ect... until it has scanned out a pie shaped slice image into the body.

> But how does it localize points in the x-y plane, forming a detailed
>   2D image?

Typically the transducer is a phased array and the pulsed beam is formed by adjusting the delays between array elements before pulsing the scan head when transmitting, or before summing the echoes together when receiving. (Goggle: beam forming and phased arrays)

Comment: Very cool. So when the beam is aimed in a particular direction $\theta$, the only significant received echoes come from the line pointing out of the transducer at angle $\theta$?

Comment: Right, and the time samples are the image pixels down that line.

Comment: @WillG, Re, "the only significant received echoes come from the line pointing out of the transducer at angle ?" More accurate to say that the phased array rejects signals coming from other directions. Wikipedia's [phased array page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phased_array) does a good job of showing how a phased array transmits a directional signal. What it doesn't show is that the array works both ways: It's directional characteristic when receiving is the same as when transmitting.